# how to write large amounts of data into pipes in c

Tags: c, pipe

For my systems programming class, I'm trying to communicate between a parent and child process using a pipe. I have a large amount of text (>64kB) that I want to send to a child process using a pipe. The child process will periodically read the text.
While writing, how do I check if the pipe is full? Also, how do I repeatedly check if the buffer has been emptied (by being read by the child process) and write the next chunk to the buffer?
I am aware that I could write the entire string out to a file, but I was just curious if there was a way to achieve this using a pipe.

Comment: Well if you continue to write, it will block until the child has read some data, but I'm assuming that's not what you want?

Comment: And you didn't try to make this work for a good reason?  What on Earth might be that reason?

Comment: What if I make another child process to write into the pipe? This would take care of the blocking problem for the parent process, wouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't try to make it work because I just implemented it using a temporary file instead. I had a feeling that would turn out to be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pipes](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) are blocking (unless you set it to be non-blocking). That solves your both issues.